# Retrieve data from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

Im want to retrieve and insert an array of images inside an array of projects. 
My array of projects has this config:

```
Array (
    [projectos] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
        [id_projecto] => 1
        [titulo] => Titulo do projecto
        [descricao] => DescriÃ§Ã£o
        [data] => 0000-00-00
        [id_categoria] => 3
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [id_projecto] => 5
        [titulo] => Teste
        [descricao] => Teste
        [data] => 2014-07-02
        [id_categoria] => 2
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object (
        [id_projecto] => 7
        [titulo] => Teste Projecto
        [descricao] => Yo
        [data] => 2014-07-02
        [id_categoria] => 3
        )
    )
)
```

And this is how i made the loop to **retrieve images and insert an array inside each project**.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($data['projectos']); $i++)
{
    $data['projectos'][$i]['imagens'][] = $this->imagem_model->get_many_by('id_projecto', $data['projectos'][$i]->id_projecto);
}
```

The result of this is a blank page which in Codeigniter very often means an error in PHP syntax which i can't see how!

The `get_many_by()` function is working fine and it's not the problem. I'm using Codeigniter Framework, the latest release.

Note: if i use this loop, the result is fine but it's not with the data format i want:

```
foreach ($data['projectos'] as $row)
{
    $data['projectos']['imagens'][] = $this->imagem_model->get_many_by('id_projecto',$row->id_projecto);            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access an object like an array. `$data['projectos'][$i]['imagens']` should be more like `$data['projectos'][$i]->imagens`... and you need to declare that class to have that public variable, initialized as an empty array before you try to append to it.

```
$data['projectos'][$i]->imagens = array();
// ...
$data['projectos'][$i]->imagens[] = 'a value';
```

But why do that? I suspect the `get_many_by` function already returns an array. So all you need to do is change your `for` loop to contain this declaration so that the array is just assigned to this Object variable:

```
$data['projectos'][$i]->imagens = $this->imagem_model->get_many_by('id_projecto', $data['projectos'][$i]->id_projecto);
```

Comment: Silly me. Thank you for your help! It worked exactly how i wanted! Have a nice day!